# I can't submit json, scv, txt files to Solr

Tags: json, csv, solr, full-text-search, text-search

I am working on Solr. I can submit XML files but when i submit JSON, CSV or txt files: "Unsupported ContentType: application/octet-stream Not in: [application/xml, application/csv, application/json, text/json, text/csv, text/xml, application/javabin]"

**Error:** https://ibb.co/dcyV05

Do you have any suggestion ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you create core under documents there is a **Request-Handler (qt)** which is initially **/update**. If you change **Document Type** to **File Upload** you can't submit your json or csv files.

To solve this problem change **Request-Handler (qt)** to **/update/extract**. After that change there will be no error when you submit your files.

Answer (score 0):

yes, add the correct content type info to your POST, for example for json payload:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
 'http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection/update/json/docs' --data-binary '
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Doc 1"
}'
```

Comment: use curl for testing, you will be able to set any and every param you need. Maybe the web app is not setting the right content type when uploading a file.